# SSIS package with 3rd party component executed via sql server agent

Tags: sql-server, dll, deployment, ssis, etl

We have developed a SSIS package using a 3rd party component for connecting to SharePoint and trying to execute it via SQL server agent through file system. We have placed the package on App server. 
DO we need to install the 3rd party component on the App server or DataBase server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should register the used DLL on the Database Server *(assuming that is the deployment server - where the package is executed)*.

If the package is not running on the App server, then there is no need to install third party component on it.

**Very useful articles for 3rd party component deployment**

- [Deploying and Testing Custom SSIS Components](http://bi-polar23.blogspot.com/2008/05/deploying-and-testing-custom-ssis.html)
- [Adding Custom Components to SSIS](http://agilebi.com/mcole/2009/08/18/adding-custom-components-to-ssis/)

Comment: package is placed on the app server and we are executing it through sql server agent through file system. So, if we execute the package, will it run on the app server or database server

Comment: I think that it will run on database server

Comment: @Vamshi there is no need that ssis is installed on App Server. So it is clear that the package will run on Database Server